# FactoryGirl has_many association with validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a standard `has_many` relationship (Booking has many Orders) with validation that a Booking does not get saved without at least one Order.  I'm trying to replicate this with my FactoryGirl factories but the validation is preventing me from doing so.

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  validates :orders, presence: true
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :booking
end
```

Here are my FactoyGirl factory specifications for each model as followed from FactoryGirl's GitHub wiki page.

```
FactoryGirl.define do                                                    

  factory :booking do                                                                                                                   
    factory :booking_with_orders do

      ignore do                                                                                                                         
        orders_count 1                                                                                                                  
      end                                                                                                                               

      before(:create) do |booking, evaluator|                                                                                           
        FactoryGirl.create_list(:order, evaluator.orders_count, booking: booking)                                                       
      end                                                                                                                               
    end                                                                                                                                 
  end 

  factory :order do
    booking
  end

end
```

When I try to run `FactoryGirl.create(:booking_with_orders)` from my spec, I get:

```
Failure/Error: @booking = FactoryGirl.create(:booking_with_orders)
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
  Validation failed: Orders can't be blank
```

It seems like the check for the validation is running even before `before(:create) [...]` which would theoretically create the Orders for the Booking.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047793/factory-girl-error-with-has-many-relationship) recommends not adding `has_many` relationships to your factories but I would like to solve this anyways if there is a good way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Wat? Impossible? Not at all.

Just change your code to something like this:

```
after :build do |booking, evaluator|
  booking.orders << FactoryGirl.build_list(:order, evaluator.orders_count, booking: nil)
end
```

Comment: You mean `booking.orders << ` but otherwise, this was the answer for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this answer pointed me in the right direction to [solve my own issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32410038/179570).

Comment: I owe you the internet equivalent of a beer

Answer (score 2):

Taking off from @jassa's answer, if you just need to add a single (required) associated record with a specific attribute, this pattern worked for me:

```
factory :booking do
  ignore do
    order_name "name"
  end

  after :build do |factory, evaluator|
    factory.orders << FactoryGirl.build(:order, name: evaluator.order_name, booking: nil)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an overly simplistic observation but what you're trying to do is in effect make sure that the `Order` exists before the `Booking`, which is impossible, as the `Order` cannot exist without its `booking_id` (meaning that the `Booking` needs to be created first).

There's nothing wrong with a has_many relationship in your factories, it's your validation that is a problem. Does this currently work in your application? How do you save your records in that case? What is the flow for creating Orders and Bookings?

Even the infamous `accepts_nested_attributes_for` won't help you here.

My advice is to rethink your record saving and validation strategy so that it is a little more sane.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good consideration but everything is working in my application with the validation.  Here is my flow: `@booking = Booking.new(params[:booking])` `@booking.orders << Order.new(params[:order])` `@booking.save`.

Comment: @ErikNomitch Have you tried the `after(:build)` callback instead of `before(:create)`? How exactly is your validation on `Booking` set up? I guess the real crux of the issue is that FactoryGirl probably wants to create these objects in isolation, which makes sense from a testing point of view, but when you create them as you just noted in your comment they are created together. This kind of coupling usually leads to headaches.