# Using FactoryGirl for resource that belongs to 2 other resources and validates their id's in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec2

My associations aren't so complex but I've hit a wall making them work with FactoryGirl:

Text: blast_id:integer recipient_id:integer

```
class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blast
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User"

  validates :blast_id, presence: true  
  validates :recipient_id, presence: true
end
```

Blast: content:string author_id:integer

```
class Blast < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  has_many :texts

  validates :author_id, presence: true
end
```

User: name:string, etc. etc.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blasts, foreign_key: "author_id"

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

In FactoryGirl I've got:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user, aliases: [:author, :recipient] do |u|
    sequence(:name)   { Faker::Name.first_name }
  end

  factory :blast do
    author
    content "Lorem ipsum"

    ignore do
      texts_count 1
    end
    after :build do |blast, evaluator|
      blast.texts << FactoryGirl.build_list(:text, evaluator.texts_count, blast: nil, recipient: FactoryGirl.create(:user) ) 
    end
  end

  factory :text do
    blast
    association :recipient, factory: :user
  end
end
```

Finally, some specs which all fail because `Texts is not valid`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Text do
  User.destroy_all
  Blast.destroy_all
  Text.destroy_all
  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:blast) { FactoryGirl.create(:blast, author: user) }
  let(:text) { blast.texts.first }

  subject { text }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "attributes" do
    it { should respond_to(:blast) }
    it { should respond_to(:recipient) }
    its(:blast) { should == blast }
    its(:recipient) { should == recipient }
  end

  describe "when blast_id is not present" do
    before { text.blast_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when recipient_id is not present" do
    before { text.recipient_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

end
```

All the specs fail on `FactoryGirl` blast creation with:

```
  1) Text 
     Failure/Error: let!(:blast) { FactoryGirl.create(:blast, author: user) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Texts is invalid
     # ./spec/models/text_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've tried various iterations of the association code in the [FactoryGirl docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) and other question answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851382/factorygirl-has-many-association-with-validation) but my situation is different enough that I can't get it to work.

If you've made it this far, thank you!  Super grateful for any leads.

Comment: Try to remove `blast: nil` in line `FactoryGirl.build_list(:text, evaluator.texts_count, blast: nil, recipient: FactoryGirl.create(:user) )`. I think Rails is clever enough and `blast` will be set automatically after perfoming `<<` (sorry - I can't recheck it now myself).

Comment: Thanks for input, @gotva, but when I remove the `blast: nil` I get the interesting error, `Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factory for "blast" should look like

```
factory :blast do
  author
  content "Lorem ipsum"

  ignore do
    texts_count 1
  end

  after :build do |blast, evaluator|
    blast.texts << FactoryGirl.build_list(:text, evaluator.texts_count, blast: blast, recipient: FactoryGirl.create(:user) ) 
  end
end
```

In other words, you immediately create the correct "parent" by connecting the newly created blast to the newly created tekst

To further dry your code, have a look at https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#configure-your-test-suite, describing how to get rid of using "FactoryGirl." over and over again by setting

```
config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
```

once in your settings

Comment: Thanks for answer, @Danny, but I still get the same error.  I'm going to install [pry](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry) and see if that helps.  Also, very much appreciate your directing me to the FactoryGirl syntax methods.

Comment: I don't get it. What is line ./spec/models/text_spec.rb:8 referring to? As far as I can judge from your code, there is no validation for texts?

Comment: Hi @Danny.  Grateful for your patience with me. `/spec/models/text_spec.rb:8` refers to the line of code: `let!(:blast) { FactoryGirl.create(:blast, author: user) }`  Also, Text has two validations requiring the presence of both blast_id and recipient_id.  That code is present in the included code for the Text model.

Comment: I have exactly the same code in several of my factories, and they work like a charm. Only difference I see is that you are validating on the _id, whereas I am validating on the association itself, using e.g. validates_presence_of :blast. I wouldn't think this could cause a problem, but you never know, as at some point in time there is already an object, but no id yet, especially for "blast". Give it a try and replace all your _id validations.

Comment: Excellent, @Danny!  That was my problem.  Thank you.  Much positive karma being sent your way...