# Rails has many association with validation and factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Consider a rails project with models `User`, `List` and `Item`.

`list.rb`

```
has_many :items
#check if the list has at least one item during save
validate :must_have_one_item_at_least
```

For this I have a factory like this:

```
factory :ordered_list_unpublished, traits: :ordered do
  transient do
    items_count 5
  end
  after(:build) do |list, evaluator|
    create_list(:item, evaluator.items_count, user: list.user, list: list)
  end
end
```

But the validation keeps failing when I do `create(:ordered_list_unpublished)` because of `Validation failed: Items count is zero. Atleast one item must be present.`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `create` which will try and save the item into your database once it is created. The after `:build` callback will be run AFTER the create is finished, therefore it is trying to save into your database before it has added the items that would allow it to pass validation.

Instead of `create` try

```
build(:ordered_list_unpublished)
```

and you should be able to proceed as this will not attempt to save the model out.

Probably need to think about if you really require validation for the number of items to be greater than one as there may be situations where you want to create it first and add items later.

Another consideration, when you validate, you can specify to only validate on the first create, or to ignore the first create and then only validate when you are are updating:

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true, on: :create
validates :email, uniqueness: true, on: :update
```

Answer (score 0):

This change to the factory made it work:

```
factory :ordered_list_unpublished, traits: [:ordered, :published] do
  transient do
    items_count 5
  end

  before(:create) do |list, evaluator|
    list.items << build_list(:item, evaluator.items_count, user: list.user, list: list)
  end
end
```

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16409754/2143985)