# FactoryGirl nested transient has_many association with validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

My problem is that of [FactoryGirl has_many association with validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851382/factorygirl-has-many-association-with-validation), with the added complexity of the association being a "transient" attribute, and is quite nested

ie. my classes are (I'm using mongoid, assume `Mongoid::Document` is included in all models)

```
class User
  has_many :company_admin_profiles
end

class CompanyAdminProfile
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user # Cannot exist standalone
end

class Company
  has_many :company_admin_profiles

  validate :has_at_least_one_admin
end
```

So far with FactoryGirl I've written

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    ...

    trait(:company_admin) do
      transient do
        company_admins_count 1
        company { create(:company, admins_count: 0) }
      end

      after(:build) do |user, evaluator|
        create_list(:company_admin_profile, evaluator.company_admins_count,
          company: evaluator.company,
          user: user,
          first_name: user.first_name,
          last_name: user.last_name,
          email: user.email)
      end
    end

    factory :company_admin_user, traits: [:company_admin]

  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company_admin_profile, class: Company::Admin do
    company
  end
end


FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do

    transient do
      admins_count 1 # need one admin to pass validation
    end

    after(:build) do |company, evaluator|
      build_list(:company_admin_user, evaluator.admins_count,
          company: company)

    end
  end
end
```

I've tried several variations on this, the last error is

```
* company - Attribute already defined: company (FactoryGirl::AttributeDefinitionError)
* company_admin_profile - Attribute already defined: company (FactoryGirl::AttributeDefinitionError)
* company_admin_user - Attribute already defined: company (FactoryGirl::AttributeDefinitionError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw an upvote on the question, so maybe someone is actually interested in the solution I have for now.

I don't remember exactly where the problem was, but here's a code that works :

```
# factories/company.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    ...

    transient do
      admins_count 1 # need one admin to pass validation
    end

    after(:build) do |comp, evaluator|
      if evaluator.admins_count == 1
        build(:company_admin_user, company: comp)
      end
    end
  end
end

# factories/user.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    ...

    after(:build) do |user|
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end

    # Company admin
    trait(:company_admin) do
      transient do
        company_admins_count 1
        company { build(:company, admins_count: 0) }
      end

      after(:build) do |user, evaluator|
        create_list(:company_admin_profile, evaluator.company_admins_count,
          company: evaluator.company,
          user: user)
        evaluator.company.save
      end
    end

    factory :company_admin_user, traits: [:company_admin]
  end
end

# factories/company_admin_profile.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company_admin_profile, class: CompanyAdminProfile do
    ...
    company
  end
end
```